# What is the kaioken-like red aura produces by Chichi when she's mad?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-super

In episode 75 of DBS, Chichi produces a strong red aura when she was angry. Similarly in DBZ, Chichi seems to produce the same red ki when Maron called her an old lady in the Garlic Jr. Saga. It's unlikely to be a kaioken because the dragon ball dedicated wiki doesn't include her in the kaioken users list. What exactly is this red aura? We don't see it on other Z Fighters except for Goku.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well from my understanding. It comes from dragon ball and it's just a chi-chi trope. Ya know tsundere girl gets all firey when she gets mad? But I don't have any actual proof since I have seen all of the original Dragon Ball.

Comment: I think it's a joke that the animators make to show she gets very powerful when she's angry and give her the red color of the kaioken because it's supposed to be powerful, but may be Goku taught her the kaioken, who knows, never stated in the series.

Comment: it might have something to do with the powers she demonstrated back in Dragonball. remember when she and Goku first met as children, scared she fired a beam from her forehead and launched a blade from her helmet, both very destructive.

Answer (score 1):

It's just for humor. This is seen in a lot of anime, including one piece, where female character appears to be stronger than the protagonist as well when angry, and proceed to beat them up. Don't think too much into it.

Comment: Would you like to furnish some evidence as to your claim? I can similarly claim the opposite and we'd be no closer to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply used to show that she is angry. Red colour is often associated with anger and showing it as an aura just highlights that she is really very angry.

We can safely rule out that it isn't some sort of hidden power that she has or she would have used it in the face of danger. This can further be supported, if you recall, the scene in Dragon Ball GT when Baby had taken over Goten. He initially thought that Chi-Chi was the strongest on Earth by looking into Goten's memories and emotions. He later realised that Chi-Chi wasn't the strongest but Goten felt that way towards her because she was his mother and he respected her and was afraid of her when she became angry. By this we can safely assume that Human or Super Saiyan you don't want to be around - and especailly be the cause of Chi-Chi's anger. And what better way to illustrate this than a fiery red aura of anger?